# Create custom pages in php

Tags: php, movie

I am currently developing a movie directory in php, the site is connected to my database and the data is displayed
in a table, the elements of the section "title" have a link (clickable), and I want it to refer these links to a page movie.php/Aname = "idOfTheMovie" (link Personalized) which displays the info of the database like the poster, the director...

Php code of index.php:

```
  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","movie");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM allmovie");

echo "
<center>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Director</th>
<th>My score</th>
<th>imdb note</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Poster link</th>
</tr>
</center>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a target='_self' href='movie.php?Aname=" . $row['id'] ."'>". $row['title'] . "</a>";"" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['director'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['imdb_score'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['poster_link'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I try many codes for the movie.php page but I don't find the good
Thanks :)

Comment: So...what is your question?

Comment: Yeah, what should movie.php do, exactly? And what have you tried so far that did not work. If you are able to get this script, surely you would have some idea where to start.

Comment: `?Aname` = `$_GET['Aname']` and assign a variable to it, then query based on that with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I try to make the movie.php page and top display the information of the movie of the link on the page, I try many code but I don't find the good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the php $_GET[] global variable to get your goal.

example: movie.php

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['Aname'];

if (empty($id)) { 
    echo "an error occured"; 
} else {
    $code = 'SELECT * FROM allmovie where id = "$id"'; 
    $data = mysqli_query($code);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        //some codes
    }
}
?>
```

hope it helps. correct me if i made a mistake.

Comment: Change value of $code to: 

    $code = " SELECT * FROM allmovie WHERE id = " . $id . ; 

And then change $data to:

    $data = mysqli_query($con,$code) ;

Comment: When I put echo $data; it tell me "Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /Users/francois/Sites/movie.php on line 64
"

Comment: Did your code look like this: 

 movie.php

    <?php 
    $id = $_GET['Aname'];

    if (empty($id)) { 
        echo "an error occured"; 
    } else {
        $code = "SELECT * FROM allmovie where id = ".$id. ; 
        $data = mysqli_query($con,$code);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
      echo .$row[title]. "<br/> directed by: " .$row[director]. 
//e.t.c 
;
        }
    }
     ?>